# “TypeError: unhashable type: 'Dimension'” with BatchNormalization(axis=CHANNEL_AXIS)(input)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, ipython

I have the following ResNet 3D architecture that I got from github. It is the Keras implementation of R3D. This architecture is intended to train models on video classification

```
## Resnet 3D architecture
# Taken from https://github.com/JihongJu/keras-resnet3d/blob/master/resnet3d/resnet3d.py

def _bn_relu(input):
    """Helper to build a BN -> relu block (by @raghakot)."""
    norm = BatchNormalization(axis=CHANNEL_AXIS)(input)
    return Activation("relu")(norm)

def _conv_bn_relu3D(**conv_params):
    filters = conv_params["filters"]
    kernel_size = conv_params["kernel_size"]
    strides = conv_params.setdefault("strides", (1, 1, 1))
    kernel_initializer = conv_params.setdefault(
        "kernel_initializer", "he_normal")
    padding = conv_params.setdefault("padding", "same")
    kernel_regularizer = conv_params.setdefault("kernel_regularizer",
                                                l2(1e-4))

    def f(input):
        conv = Conv3D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size,
                      strides=strides, kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
                      padding=padding,
                      kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer)(input)
        return _bn_relu(conv)

    return f

def _bn_relu_conv3d(**conv_params):
    """Helper to build a  BN -> relu -> conv3d block."""
    filters = conv_params["filters"]
    kernel_size = conv_params["kernel_size"]
    strides = conv_params.setdefault("strides", (1, 1, 1))
    kernel_initializer = conv_params.setdefault("kernel_initializer",
                                                "he_normal")
    padding = conv_params.setdefault("padding", "same")
    kernel_regularizer = conv_params.setdefault("kernel_regularizer",
                                                l2(1e-4))

    def f(input):
        activation = _bn_relu(input)
        return Conv3D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size,
                      strides=strides, kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
                      padding=padding,
                      kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer)(activation)
    return f


def _shortcut3d(input, residual):
    """3D shortcut to match input and residual and merges them with "sum"."""
    stride_dim1 = math.ceil(int(input.shape[DIM1_AXIS]) \
        / int(residual.shape[DIM1_AXIS]))
    stride_dim2 = math.ceil(int(input.shape[DIM2_AXIS]) \
        / int(residual.shape[DIM2_AXIS]))
    stride_dim3 = math.ceil(int(input.shape[DIM3_AXIS]) \
        / int(residual.shape[DIM3_AXIS]))
    equal_channels = int(residual.shape[CHANNEL_AXIS]) \
        == int(input.shape[CHANNEL_AXIS])

    shortcut = input
    if stride_dim1 > 1 or stride_dim2 > 1 or stride_dim3 > 1 \
            or not equal_channels:
        shortcut = Conv3D(
            filters=residual.shape[CHANNEL_AXIS],
            kernel_size=(1, 1, 1),
            strides=(stride_dim1, stride_dim2, stride_dim3),
            kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="valid",
            kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-4)
            )(input)
    return add([shortcut, residual])


def _residual_block3d(block_function, filters, kernel_regularizer, repetitions,
                      is_first_layer=False):
    def f(input):
        for i in range(repetitions):
            strides = (1, 1, 1)
            if i == 0 and not is_first_layer:
                strides = (2, 2, 2)
            input = block_function(filters=filters, strides=strides,
                                   kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
                                   is_first_block_of_first_layer=(
                                       is_first_layer and i == 0)
                                   )(input)
        return input

    return f


def basic_block(filters, strides=(1, 1, 1), kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-4),
                is_first_block_of_first_layer=False):
    """Basic 3 X 3 X 3 convolution blocks. Extended from raghakot's 2D impl."""
    def f(input):
        if is_first_block_of_first_layer:
            # don't repeat bn->relu since we just did bn->relu->maxpool
            conv1 = Conv3D(filters=filters, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
                           strides=strides, padding="same",
                           kernel_initializer="he_normal",
                           kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer
                           )(input)
        else:
            conv1 = _bn_relu_conv3d(filters=filters,
                                    kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
                                    strides=strides,
                                    kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer
                                    )(input)

        residual = _bn_relu_conv3d(filters=filters, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
                                   kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer
                                   )(conv1)
        return _shortcut3d(input, residual)

    return f


def bottleneck(filters, strides=(1, 1, 1), kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-4),
               is_first_block_of_first_layer=False):
    """Basic 3 X 3 X 3 convolution blocks. Extended from raghakot's 2D impl."""
    def f(input):
        if is_first_block_of_first_layer:
            # don't repeat bn->relu since we just did bn->relu->maxpool
            conv_1_1 = Conv3D(filters=filters, kernel_size=(1, 1, 1),
                              strides=strides, padding="same",
                              kernel_initializer="he_normal",
                              kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer
                              )(input)
        else:
            conv_1_1 = _bn_relu_conv3d(filters=filters, kernel_size=(1, 1, 1),
                                       strides=strides,
                                       kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer
                                       )(input)

        conv_3_3 = _bn_relu_conv3d(filters=filters, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
                                   kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer
                                   )(conv_1_1)
        residual = _bn_relu_conv3d(filters=filters * 4, kernel_size=(1, 1, 1),
                                   kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer
                                   )(conv_3_3)

        return _shortcut3d(input, residual)

    return f


def _handle_data_format():
    global DIM1_AXIS
    global DIM2_AXIS
    global DIM3_AXIS
    global CHANNEL_AXIS
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_last':
        DIM1_AXIS = 1
        DIM2_AXIS = 2
        DIM3_AXIS = 3
        CHANNEL_AXIS = 4
    else:
        CHANNEL_AXIS = 1
        DIM1_AXIS = 2
        DIM2_AXIS = 3
        DIM3_AXIS = 4


def _get_block(identifier):
    if isinstance(identifier, six.string_types):
        res = globals().get(identifier)
        if not res:
            raise ValueError('Invalid {}'.format(identifier))
        return res
    return identifier


class Resnet3DBuilder(object):
    """ResNet3D."""

    @staticmethod
    def build(input_shape, num_outputs, block_fn, repetitions, reg_factor):
        """Instantiate a vanilla ResNet3D keras model.
        # Arguments
            input_shape: Tuple of input shape in the format
            (conv_dim1, conv_dim2, conv_dim3, channels) if dim_ordering='tf'
            (filter, conv_dim1, conv_dim2, conv_dim3) if dim_ordering='th'
            num_outputs: The number of outputs at the final softmax layer
            block_fn: Unit block to use {'basic_block', 'bottlenack_block'}
            repetitions: Repetitions of unit blocks
        # Returns
            model: a 3D ResNet model that takes a 5D tensor (volumetric images
            in batch) as input and returns a 1D vector (prediction) as output.
        """
        _handle_data_format()
        if len(input_shape) != 4:
            raise ValueError("Input shape should be a tuple "
                             "(conv_dim1, conv_dim2, conv_dim3, channels) "
                             "for tensorflow as backend or "
                             "(channels, conv_dim1, conv_dim2, conv_dim3) "
                             "for theano as backend")

        block_fn = _get_block(block_fn)
        input = Input(shape=input_shape)
        # first conv
        conv1 = _conv_bn_relu3D(filters=64, kernel_size=(7, 7, 7),
                                strides=(2, 2, 2),
                                kernel_regularizer=l2(reg_factor)
                                )(input)
        pool1 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(3, 3, 3), strides=(2, 2, 2),
                             padding="same")(conv1)

        # repeat blocks
        block = pool1
        filters = 64
        for i, r in enumerate(repetitions):
            block = _residual_block3d(block_fn, filters=filters,
                                      kernel_regularizer=l2(reg_factor),
                                      repetitions=r, is_first_layer=(i == 0)
                                      )(block)
            filters *= 2

        # last activation
        block_output = _bn_relu(block)

        # average poll and classification
        pool2 = AveragePooling3D(pool_size=(block.shape[DIM1_AXIS],
                                            block.shape[DIM2_AXIS],
                                            block.shape[DIM3_AXIS]),
                                 strides=(1, 1, 1))(block_output)
        flatten1 = Flatten()(pool2)
        if num_outputs > 1:
            dense = Dense(units=num_outputs,
                          kernel_initializer="he_normal",
                          activation="softmax",
                          kernel_regularizer=l2(reg_factor))(flatten1)
        else:
            dense = Dense(units=num_outputs,
                          kernel_initializer="he_normal",
                          activation="sigmoid",
                          kernel_regularizer=l2(reg_factor))(flatten1)

        model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=dense)
        return model

    @staticmethod
    def build_resnet_18(input_shape, num_outputs, reg_factor=1e-4):
        """Build resnet 18."""
        return Resnet3DBuilder.build(input_shape, num_outputs, basic_block,
                                     [2, 2, 2, 2], reg_factor=reg_factor)

    @staticmethod
    def build_resnet_34(input_shape, num_outputs, reg_factor=1e-4):
        """Build resnet 34."""
        return Resnet3DBuilder.build(input_shape, num_outputs, basic_block,
                                     [3, 4, 6, 3], reg_factor=reg_factor)

    @staticmethod
    def build_resnet_50(input_shape, num_outputs, reg_factor=1e-4):
        """Build resnet 50."""
        return Resnet3DBuilder.build(input_shape, num_outputs, bottleneck,
                                     [3, 4, 6, 3], reg_factor=reg_factor)

    @staticmethod
    def build_resnet_101(input_shape, num_outputs, reg_factor=1e-4):
        """Build resnet 101."""
        return Resnet3DBuilder.build(input_shape, num_outputs, bottleneck,
                                     [3, 4, 23, 3], reg_factor=reg_factor)

    @staticmethod
    def build_resnet_152(input_shape, num_outputs, reg_factor=1e-4):
        """Build resnet 152."""
        return Resnet3DBuilder.build(input_shape, num_outputs, bottleneck,
                                     [3, 8, 36, 3], reg_factor=reg_factor)
```

When I train the network on videos, I get the following error :

```
Error: unhashable type: 'Dimension'

  File "<ipython-input-29-788d091a6763>", line 1961, in main
    trained_model_name)
  File "<ipython-input-29-788d091a6763>", line 1805, in train
    model = train_load_model(model_type, training_condition, sample_input.shape, nb_classes)
  File "<ipython-input-29-788d091a6763>", line 1684, in train_load_model
    model = Resnet3DBuilder.build_resnet_50((96, 96, 96, 1), 20)
  File "<ipython-input-29-788d091a6763>", line 1543, in build_resnet_50
    [3, 4, 6, 3], reg_factor=reg_factor)
  File "<ipython-input-29-788d091a6763>", line 1501, in build
    )(block)
  File "<ipython-input-29-788d091a6763>", line 1372, in f
    )(input)
  File "<ipython-input-29-788d091a6763>", line 1419, in f
    )(input)
  File "<ipython-input-29-788d091a6763>", line 1334, in f
    activation = _bn_relu(input)
  File "<ipython-input-29-788d091a6763>", line 1300, in _bn_relu
    norm = BatchNormalization(axis=CHANNEL_AXIS)(input)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 440, in __call__
    self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 345, in assert_input_compatibility
    x_shape[int(axis)] not in {value, None}):
```

I have the following Tensorflow, Keras, and Python versions :

- Tensorflow : 1.15.0
- Keras : 2.2.4
- Python : 3.6

Can you tell me how to solve this error ? I saw that casting Dimension to int solved the problem elsewhere, but I don't know what I should cast here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, we need to cast every shape access to int.

**Example :**
`residual.shape[CHANNEL_AXIS]` needs to be rewritten `int(residual.shape[CHANNEL_AXIS])`

The new version of the code is as follows :

```
## Resnet 3D architecture
# Taken from https://github.com/JihongJu/keras-resnet3d/blob/master/resnet3d/resnet3d.py

def _bn_relu(input):
    """Helper to build a BN -> relu block (by @raghakot)."""
    norm = BatchNormalization(axis=CHANNEL_AXIS)(input)
    return Activation("relu")(norm)

def _conv_bn_relu3D(**conv_params):
    filters = conv_params["filters"]
    kernel_size = conv_params["kernel_size"]
    strides = conv_params.setdefault("strides", (1, 1, 1))
    kernel_initializer = conv_params.setdefault(
        "kernel_initializer", "he_normal")
    padding = conv_params.setdefault("padding", "same")
    kernel_regularizer = conv_params.setdefault("kernel_regularizer",
                                                l2(1e-4))

    def f(input):
        conv = Conv3D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size,
                      strides=strides, kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
                      padding=padding,
                      kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer)(input)
        return _bn_relu(conv)

    return f

def _bn_relu_conv3d(**conv_params):
    """Helper to build a  BN -> relu -> conv3d block."""
    filters = conv_params["filters"]
    kernel_size = conv_params["kernel_size"]
    strides = conv_params.setdefault("strides", (1, 1, 1))
    kernel_initializer = conv_params.setdefault("kernel_initializer",
                                                "he_normal")
    padding = conv_params.setdefault("padding", "same")
    kernel_regularizer = conv_params.setdefault("kernel_regularizer",
                                                l2(1e-4))

    def f(input):
        activation = _bn_relu(input)
        return Conv3D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size,
                      strides=strides, kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
                      padding=padding,
                      kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer)(activation)
    return f


def _shortcut3d(input, residual):
    """3D shortcut to match input and residual and merges them with "sum"."""
    stride_dim1 = math.ceil(int(input.shape[DIM1_AXIS]) \
        / int(residual.shape[DIM1_AXIS]))
    stride_dim2 = math.ceil(int(input.shape[DIM2_AXIS]) \
        / int(residual.shape[DIM2_AXIS]))
    stride_dim3 = math.ceil(int(input.shape[DIM3_AXIS]) \
        / int(residual.shape[DIM3_AXIS]))
    equal_channels = int(residual.shape[CHANNEL_AXIS]) \
        == int(input.shape[CHANNEL_AXIS])

    shortcut = input
    if stride_dim1 > 1 or stride_dim2 > 1 or stride_dim3 > 1 \
            or not equal_channels:
        shortcut = Conv3D(
            filters=int(residual.shape[CHANNEL_AXIS]),
            kernel_size=(1, 1, 1),
            strides=(stride_dim1, stride_dim2, stride_dim3),
            kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="valid",
            kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-4)
            )(input)
    return add([shortcut, residual])


def _residual_block3d(block_function, filters, kernel_regularizer, repetitions,
                      is_first_layer=False):
    def f(input):
        for i in range(repetitions):
            strides = (1, 1, 1)
            if i == 0 and not is_first_layer:
                strides = (2, 2, 2)
            input = block_function(filters=filters, strides=strides,
                                   kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
                                   is_first_block_of_first_layer=(
                                       is_first_layer and i == 0)
                                   )(input)
        return input

    return f


def basic_block(filters, strides=(1, 1, 1), kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-4),
                is_first_block_of_first_layer=False):
    """Basic 3 X 3 X 3 convolution blocks. Extended from raghakot's 2D impl."""
    def f(input):
        if is_first_block_of_first_layer:
            # don't repeat bn->relu since we just did bn->relu->maxpool
            conv1 = Conv3D(filters=filters, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
                           strides=strides, padding="same",
                           kernel_initializer="he_normal",
                           kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer
                           )(input)
        else:
            conv1 = _bn_relu_conv3d(filters=filters,
                                    kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
                                    strides=strides,
                                    kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer
                                    )(input)

        residual = _bn_relu_conv3d(filters=filters, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
                                   kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer
                                   )(conv1)
        return _shortcut3d(input, residual)

    return f


def bottleneck(filters, strides=(1, 1, 1), kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-4),
               is_first_block_of_first_layer=False):
    """Basic 3 X 3 X 3 convolution blocks. Extended from raghakot's 2D impl."""
    def f(input):
        if is_first_block_of_first_layer:
            # don't repeat bn->relu since we just did bn->relu->maxpool
            conv_1_1 = Conv3D(filters=filters, kernel_size=(1, 1, 1),
                              strides=strides, padding="same",
                              kernel_initializer="he_normal",
                              kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer
                              )(input)
        else:
            conv_1_1 = _bn_relu_conv3d(filters=filters, kernel_size=(1, 1, 1),
                                       strides=strides,
                                       kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer
                                       )(input)

        conv_3_3 = _bn_relu_conv3d(filters=filters, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
                                   kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer
                                   )(conv_1_1)
        residual = _bn_relu_conv3d(filters=filters * 4, kernel_size=(1, 1, 1),
                                   kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer
                                   )(conv_3_3)

        return _shortcut3d(input, residual)

    return f


def _handle_data_format():
    global DIM1_AXIS
    global DIM2_AXIS
    global DIM3_AXIS
    global CHANNEL_AXIS
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_last':
        print("here CHANNELS last")
        DIM1_AXIS = 1
        DIM2_AXIS = 2
        DIM3_AXIS = 3
        CHANNEL_AXIS = 4
    else:
        CHANNEL_AXIS = 1
        DIM1_AXIS = 2
        DIM2_AXIS = 3
        DIM3_AXIS = 4


def _get_block(identifier):
    if isinstance(identifier, six.string_types):
        res = globals().get(identifier)
        if not res:
            raise ValueError('Invalid {}'.format(identifier))
        return res
    return identifier


class Resnet3DBuilder(object):
    """ResNet3D."""

    @staticmethod
    def build(input_shape, num_outputs, block_fn, repetitions, reg_factor):
        """Instantiate a vanilla ResNet3D keras model.
        # Arguments
            input_shape: Tuple of input shape in the format
            (conv_dim1, conv_dim2, conv_dim3, channels) if dim_ordering='tf'
            (filter, conv_dim1, conv_dim2, conv_dim3) if dim_ordering='th'
            num_outputs: The number of outputs at the final softmax layer
            block_fn: Unit block to use {'basic_block', 'bottlenack_block'}
            repetitions: Repetitions of unit blocks
        # Returns
            model: a 3D ResNet model that takes a 5D tensor (volumetric images
            in batch) as input and returns a 1D vector (prediction) as output.
        """
        _handle_data_format()
        if len(input_shape) != 4:
            raise ValueError("Input shape should be a tuple "
                             "(conv_dim1, conv_dim2, conv_dim3, channels) "
                             "for tensorflow as backend or "
                             "(channels, conv_dim1, conv_dim2, conv_dim3) "
                             "for theano as backend")

        block_fn = _get_block(block_fn)
        input = Input(shape=input_shape)
        # first conv
        conv1 = _conv_bn_relu3D(filters=64, kernel_size=(7, 7, 7),
                                strides=(2, 2, 2),
                                kernel_regularizer=l2(reg_factor)
                                )(input)
        pool1 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(3, 3, 3), strides=(2, 2, 2),
                             padding="same")(conv1)

        # repeat blocks
        block = pool1
        filters = 64
        for i, r in enumerate(repetitions):
            block = _residual_block3d(block_fn, filters=filters,
                                      kernel_regularizer=l2(reg_factor),
                                      repetitions=r, is_first_layer=(i == 0)
                                      )(block)
            filters *= 2

        # last activation
        block_output = _bn_relu(block)

        # average poll and classification
        pool2 = AveragePooling3D(pool_size=(int(block.shape[DIM1_AXIS]),
                                            int(block.shape[DIM2_AXIS]),
                                            int(block.shape[DIM3_AXIS])),
                                 strides=(1, 1, 1))(block_output)
        flatten1 = Flatten()(pool2)
        if num_outputs > 1:
            dense = Dense(units=num_outputs,
                          kernel_initializer="he_normal",
                          activation="softmax",
                          kernel_regularizer=l2(reg_factor))(flatten1)
        else:
            dense = Dense(units=num_outputs,
                          kernel_initializer="he_normal",
                          activation="sigmoid",
                          kernel_regularizer=l2(reg_factor))(flatten1)

        model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=dense)
        return model

    @staticmethod
    def build_resnet_18(input_shape, num_outputs, reg_factor=1e-4):
        """Build resnet 18."""
        return Resnet3DBuilder.build(input_shape, num_outputs, basic_block,
                                     [2, 2, 2, 2], reg_factor=reg_factor)

    @staticmethod
    def build_resnet_34(input_shape, num_outputs, reg_factor=1e-4):
        """Build resnet 34."""
        return Resnet3DBuilder.build(input_shape, num_outputs, basic_block,
                                     [3, 4, 6, 3], reg_factor=reg_factor)

    @staticmethod
    def build_resnet_50(input_shape, num_outputs, reg_factor=1e-4):
        """Build resnet 50."""
        return Resnet3DBuilder.build(input_shape, num_outputs, bottleneck,
                                     [3, 4, 6, 3], reg_factor=reg_factor)

    @staticmethod
    def build_resnet_101(input_shape, num_outputs, reg_factor=1e-4):
        """Build resnet 101."""
        return Resnet3DBuilder.build(input_shape, num_outputs, bottleneck,
                                     [3, 4, 23, 3], reg_factor=reg_factor)

    @staticmethod
    def build_resnet_152(input_shape, num_outputs, reg_factor=1e-4):
        """Build resnet 152."""
        return Resnet3DBuilder.build(input_shape, num_outputs, bottleneck,
                                     [3, 8, 36, 3], reg_factor=reg_factor)
```

The problem does not occur with the latest versions of Keras and Tensorflow, but I needed to keep the old versions of these two libraries because my other scripts couldn't run on the newest versions of Tensorflow/Keras.